# Perfectly Rounded Rectangle

Tags: java, graphics2d

When I make a RoundRectangle2D I get a rounded rectangle, but the corners don't look smooth, because I make very small rounded corners.

You can actually see the pixels so how do I make the Round Rectangle smooth.

Comment: How about adding a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Try to make the arcx and arcy 10 pixels then you can see

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you can see what looks like a staircase of pixels by the corners? Use anti-aliasing, [this article](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/graphics2D/65aliasing.html) will show you how:

If you're curious, [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antialias) explains how it works and what it really is:

Answer (score 0):

smoothing is done via "anti aliasing".
try to enable that.
For a technical background info see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing